# Making a blocking obstacle

Tags: actionscript-3, collision-detection

I'm new at ActionScript 3.0 so if you guys can help me a little.

I want to make an obstacle which block a path to player. I made this like that that I'm saving all movments to array and than if they collide it moves player to previous position. Is there another way because I think this is not the proper way to do it. And sometimes when it collides player is unable to move. Can you give me an example  :)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the only way you can ever detect a collision, but in a bit more refined way.

- You actually collide the bodies (but do not apply the change to the actual object, yet).
- Check for all colliding bodies on stage.
- Take necessary step (roll back, destroy.. anything)
- Apply the change & Render the bodies, on screen.

Considering the above as an example for flash :

```
var hero:Sprite = new Sprite();

addChild(hero);

while(1) {

   var newX = hero.x + 1; 

   if(newX < 100) 

       hero.x = newX;            
}
```

Every game should have a loop. The loop must branch out to various situations. So that's your start.

The hero object probably moves with the user interaction & the checks keep increasing, compelling you to re think the solution as your project grows more & more dense...